# How I can get specific data from API

Tags: php, json, curl

I have this JSON an I want to get just license_key.

```
{"data": {"enabled": true,"product_link": "example","license_key": "BS7X4-55UH7-ZG2EV-ME2N5","buyer_email": "example@gmail.com","uses": 0,"date": "2022-11-11T20:56:37+00:00"}}
```

I try this script but when i open it I get white page

```
<?php
$url = "https://example.com/";

$curl = curl_init($url);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);

$resp = curl_exec($curl);
curl_close($curl);

$json_decoded = json_decode($resp);

$license_key = '';

for ($i = 0; $i < count($json_decoded->{'data'}); $i++) {
            $license_key = $json_decoded->{'data'}[$i]->{'license_key'};

}

echo $license_key;
```

Comment: What have you done to debug this? I'd suggest echoing `$json_decoded` to see just what's in that variable. I'd also suggest hard coding the JSON into a variable so you can see just what's broke. It could be your code or it could be the API call that's broke, or it could be a different JSON than you are expecting. You need to figure out what's wrong before you can fix it. Saying "blank page" is basically saying "it's broke" and expecting us to do all the debugging for you. Sorry, but that's not how this site works.

Comment: `$json_decoded->{'data'}[$i]->{'license_key'};` is extra steps, `$json_decoded->data[$i]->license_key;` would suffice

Answer (score 0):

You probably have a white page because your script has an error (perhaps curl extension is not installed/enabled) and your PHP settings have error reporting disabled.

You can try enabling error reports by adding this at top of your code:

```
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
ini_set('display_startup_errors', 1);
error_reporting(E_ALL);
```

Or if that doesn't work, find a php.ini file and enable errors:

```
display_errors = on
```

If you are confused about how to do any of this, you will have to search for how to enable error reporting for your hosting system and web server.

Answer (score 0):

For your JSON with the following format (which does NOT contain any square brackets in any levels)

```
{"data": {"enabled": true,"product_link": "example","license_key": "BS7X4-55UH7-ZG2EV-ME2N5","buyer_email": "example@gmail.com","uses": 0,"date": "2022-11-11T20:56:37+00:00"}}
```

You simply need `$json_decoded->{'data'}->{'license_key'};` to get the license key

So amend to

```
<?php

$url = "http://www.createchhk.com/SOanswers/subf/1.json";

$curl = curl_init($url);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);

$resp = curl_exec($curl);
curl_close($curl);

$json_decoded = json_decode($resp);

$license_key = '';

$license_key=$json_decoded->{'data'}->{'license_key'};

echo $license_key;

/*
for ($i = 0; $i < count($json_decoded->{'data'}); $i++) {
            $license_key = $json_decoded->{'data'}[$i]->{'license_key'};
}
echo $license_key;
*/

?>
```

You may visit the following sandbox link for the result:

http://www.createchhk.com/SOanswers/subf/1.php

Answer (score 0):

Setup debugging in your development environment will help you best.

1. First install the proper xdebug in your php installation
2. Install the PHP Debug extension in you VSCode (I assume you use VSCode)
3. Install a browser extention to activate the debugger. XDebug Helper for me
   [Video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=yfJBpMsDXUQ)

In the browser activate debugging, in VSCode start the debugger. This way you can set breakpoints, read variables live and step through your code.